# How to sum three columns using django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to execute such query using djagno models:

```
SELECT id, ( first+second+third ) FROM testTable
```

Without grouping.
Was trying to find the solution using google but unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) and `annotate()`:

```
from django.db.models import F

# the sum of the three columns `first`, `second` and `third` will be
# accessible as `.my_sum`
results = my_model.objects.annotate(
                         my_sum=F('first') + F('second') + F('third'),
                       )
```